# Cannot access a specific website from router behind bridged router/modem

Tags: networking

My ISP has provided me with a CISCO EPC3928S modem/router. I have this set to Bridged mode and handle routing on my internal network using my ASUS AC68U.

I need to access a specific website for my work, but cannot access it when i am connected to the ASUS AC68U. I have tried to tracert the hostname in question and can see 5 or 6 hops from my home in Malta, through to UK before it starts to timeout.

If I switch on the wireless on the bridged CISCO EPC3928S I can access the site just fine.

Any ideas on why I cannot access this site? Or how to go about diagnosing the issue?

Comment: Does either of the routers have tcpdump or some packet capture tool?

Comment: I don't think the Cisco or the ASUS are installed with any such tool. Perhaps I could install wireshark on my laptop and get a view of what is happening when I am connecting to the internet in the following scenarios  1. DIrectly through the Cisco (In Router Mode)   2. Through the ASUS and Cisco (In Bridged Mode)?

Comment: Worth a try, but it'll likely show the same thing in both cases. I'm curious about whether the packets are different at the point they reach (or leave) the Cisco...